# what is different between if (val) { } and if (!!val) { }

Tags: javascript

I know that

> if (val) {
>   }

will evaluate to true as long as value is not:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty
- string ("")
- 0
- false

whats different to

> if (!!val) { }